# How to suppress the Microsoft Edge custom protocol dialog warning?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

We are trying to suppress the dialog thrown by Microsoft Edge browser when we try to start an app using the protocol handler.

We have seen that when we try windows specific protocols like ms-clock://, microsoftmusic://, microsoftvideo:// the Edge browser doesn't throw up any warning.

If we try the same with our custom app, registered with a custom protocol, it throws up the warning dialog.

Is there any way to suppress this warning?

Comment: Since Windows 10 isn't shipping yet, final docs have probably _not_ been published.  (Expect those to appear throughout release day, as the publishing servers push them out.)  As a result, it's going to be difficult to point to definitive sources for help.  I do note, however, that protocols are often defined in the registry (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377513(v=vs.85).aspx) and reviewing the definitions of the protocols you cite may provide clues.  Do be aware, however, that Microsoft does not formally document the registry.  Hack at your own risk.

Comment: I've just tested this in a brand new Windows app and it worked without prompting me about the switch. What custom protocol are you using? There are reserved/forbidden protocol strings. Also, if you register a protocol that is already assigned to an app, it will prompt the user to choose which app they want to open.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the warning that you're seeing?

Comment: I am not able to attach any images, please try to open a torrent magnet link from pirate bay site in Microsoft edge browser, You will see the dialog, asking the user to open the uTorrent app or not. **(Note: You should have the uTorrent app installed)**

Answer (score 2):

Turned out it is could be fixed quote easily: select menu option "Open page in internet explorer", then try to open magnet link and uncheck "Always ask when opening..." check box. After that both IE and Edge will open such links without confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove url protocol dialog prompt in EDGE browser, if you build your windows app using windows universal platform.